# How to repair cracks around drain

Tags: drain, cement

Every time it rains (or we use the washing machine or sink), water goes down the cracks around the drain. And then it gets sucked up into the kitchen through the cement floor.

How do I repair it? And are there any materials you recommend?

Also, is there a temporary fix that I can do? That might help until it is fixed properly.

Thanks.

[image]

**UPDATE**: Fixed now -- until the main works start. Thanks for the help.

[image: after]

Comment: That looks so 18th century. Can't you install modern plumbing to take the concrete box out of the equation?

Comment: Yes, the modern plumbing will come with a planned redevelopment. Right now, I'm just looking for a quick fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the quick fix column, I'd get a bucket of concrete waterproofer or roofing sealant and slather it over the entire inside of that receptacle. You could fill the largest cracks with some vinyl cement patch first if you don't think it'll hold with just the sealant.

Don't build anything. You'd just have to seal that, too.

Answer (score 3):

I'm no cement guy, but it would seem to me that if you made a dam around the existing drain (cut some plywood a few inches high into a level box and nail it or glue it etc. together) and pour some new cement around the drain, I would think that would fill in the cracks & fix it. I would also trowel a slight angle towards the drain so it would be forced down instead of pooling anywhere.